# Using href: Calling a javascript function via another domain

Tags: javascript, html

**Setup:**

> `Site A` lists courses with a `registration` link.
>   This registration link is an `anchor` with `javascript:register('single, '010115')`.
>   `Site A` registration link calls a predefined javascript function that sends the arguments to a form on a coldfusion page.
>   `Site B` needs to list the courses from `Site A`, and provide a `registration` link that works identically to `Site A's`.

**Test Solutions:**

> I have attempted to use the following to mimic the function call:
>
> > Included the call function into `Site B's`scripts
> >  this includes:
> >
> > - adding the full `url` that leads to the `cfm` registration page
> > - changing the function to variable form (`var register = function() {...}`)
> >
> > Included `anchor` with embedded function call

**Errors that have occurred:**

> When clicking the `registration` button, the console meets the action with: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined`

**Code:**

```
function register (RegType, CourseID){
    var f = document.forms['myForm'];

    f.RegType.value = RegType;
    f.CourseID.value = CourseID;

    f.action = "https://*****";
    f.submit();
}
```

It seems like it is borderline XSS so it's possible this won't work. If anyone has any clue as `how to run a javascript function via an anchor, when the script originates from another domain`, please share the knowledge!
Thanks in advance!
Ricky

**UPDATE**
The fix was quite simple: the form `myForm` needed to be present on `Site B` to populate and send data via js.
The issue with this fix is that the **form was at the top of the code, instead of at the end.**
May I also say, this is a hidden form for submitting the data.
Once the form was inserted at the bottom of the html elements, the form was able to be filled by the script and sent to the coldfusion page, as if it were run from `Site A`.

Thanks again, for all the help!

Comment: The error that you get is related to a field missing in your form, and not to any cross site call failing or any other fancy thing. Add the fields RegType and CourseID to the form (one of them, or both, are missing), and try again

Comment: In general, it would be a pretty bad idea to allow execution of arbitrarily injected JS from foreign pages. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your use case? If you're providing sufficient data on Site B to list the courses, why not just submit the registration request directly from there?

Comment: @Palpatim It's... complicated.. this is more to keep the client happy.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro So this IS missing a form.. I will try this and report.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro The missing form fixed the errors, but now the function just loads `Site A`. Unless there is a way to forward the arguments to the javascript function on `Site A`, I'm going to call this one closed. Thanks again.

Comment: As the form's action is a umich page, you will be redirected there as the form is submitted. Maybe you could try to send the data using AJAX, but I don't know how that will go

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Liking the suggestion. I will try this tonight.